# Java: Vector Definition

Tags: java, vector

```
l_ABC_BEANVector = utilRemote.fnGetVector("ABC_COVBEANVector");
```

What is the coding means?
Any help, i am truly appreciated it.
Thanks

Comment: We probably need more context to help you with this. What code comes before and after this statement?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that can be said with certainty is that it is calling a method called "fnGetVector" with a String literal as argument, and that the method returns some value.  If the code was following normal Java coding conventions, you could infer that 'utilRemote' was a helper object of some kind.  But there are signs that it is NOT following normal Java coding conventions.

If you want a more meaningful answer, you will need to provide a lot more context.